# Vue Js - show an input value if ENTER is pressed

Tags: vue.js

I'm a **beginner** and I done this as i will show here,
but I'm sure Vue is to make our job easier, not to complicate it. So I don't think my method is the best one. **Do you have a smarter solution?** (Obiously yes lol) Here's my effort. What do you think about it?

HTML:

```
<section id="trial">
    <input @keyup="saveInput" type="text" @keyup.enter="confirmInput" />
    <p> {{confirmedInput}} </p>
  </section>
```

JS:

```
 const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      userInput: '',
      confirmedInput: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {

  },
  computed: {

  },
  methods: {
    saveInput(event) {
      this.userInput = event.target.value;
    },
    confirmInput() {
      this.confirmedInput = this.userInput;
    }
  }
});
app.mount('#trial');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `v-model`:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#trial",
  data() {
    return {
      userInput: '',
      confirmedInput: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    confirmInput() {
      this.confirmedInput = this.userInput;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="trial">
  <section id="trial">
    <input v-model="userInput" type="text" @keyup.enter="confirmInput" />
    <p> {{confirmedInput}} </p>
  </section>
</div>
```